# Android - How the state of views are preserved during Fragment Transforamtion

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

This confuses me a lot.

I had two fragments, and I use FragmentTransaction.replace() the swap the two fragments. State of some input controls like RadioGroup and checkbox is always preserved when I switch to the other fragments and switch back again.

[image].

I set break point on my OnCreateView() of Fragment, and every swap seems to trigger the method and new views are created each time. The savedInstanceBundle is always null as well. Since the new views are created, how do they get the state of the old views?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fieldsetup_marking, container, false);
   // ...
 return v;
}
```

This effect is fine for my app, but I just want to know how it is implemented.

1. where are the states stored?
2. Where is the android SDK code to restore this (I can not find any in the class FragmentTransection).

Comment: ***onPause()***
The system calls this method as the first indication that the user is leaving the fragment (though it does not always mean the fragment is being destroyed). This is usually where you should commit any changes that should be persisted beyond the current user session (because the user might not come back).

Comment: Your onCreateView might be called - due to the search widget, if you are using it. However, a fragment is placed into a back stack managed by the host activity only when you explicitly request that the instance be saved by calling addToBackStack() during a transaction that removes the fragment.

Comment: Hi @Skynet, the onCreateView is always called based on my experiments. and states of view are always persisted magically (I did not write any code for state persistent) And my question is how does Android sdk code perform this magic.

Comment: [Read](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: The state is stored in `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` and restored in `onCreate` or `onCreateView`